# Trouble using toggle button for quiz in kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

In my quiz app, the toggle buttons are used as options to get the answer from the user. But whenever a toggle button is clicked, it is in a 'down' state for the next question, but whenever I unclick that button, the next question appears, and I am missing to answer that question. **I want that whenever a new question appears the state of all toggle buttons should be 'normal'.**
here is the code for main file:

```
import json
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.app import App

a=0
score=0
sca=0
class MyLayout(BoxLayout):
    global data
    f=open('questions.json')
    data=json.load(f)
  
    def openquestion(self):
        global a
        try:
            self.ids.ques.text=data['category1']['question'][a]   
            self.ids.opt1.text=data['category1']['options'][a][0]
            self.ids.opt2.text=data['category1']['options'][a][1]
            self.ids.opt3.text=data['category1']['options'][a][2]
            self.ids.opt4.text=data['category1']['options'][a][3]
            a+=1
        except:
            print('all questions completed')

    
    def checkscore(self,bu_id):
        global score
        global sca
        answer=data['category1']['answer'][sca]
        if(bu_id==answer):
            score+=1
        print('score: ',score,'question: ',sca+1,'button pressed: ',bu_id,'answer no:',answer)
        sca+=1

class rough(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyLayout()

if __name__=='__main__':
    rough().run()
```

here is the .kv file:

```
#:kivy 2.1.0
<QLabel@Label>:
    halign:'center'
    text_size:self.width,None
<ToggleButton>:
    size:0.6,0.4
<MyLayout>:
    orientation:'vertical'
    size:root.width,root.height
    padding:20
    spacing:10
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        size:root.width,root.height
        padding:20
        spacing:10
        BoxLayout:
            id:options
            orientation:'vertical'
            spacing:7
            QLabel:
                id:ques
                text:'Questions coming soon...'
            ToggleButton:
                group:options
                id:opt1
                text:'option01'
                on_press:
                    root.checkscore(1)
                    root.openquestion()

            ToggleButton:
                group:options
                id:opt2
                text:'option02'
                on_press:
                    root.checkscore(2)
                    root.openquestion()

            ToggleButton:
                group:options
                id:opt3
                text:'option03'
                on_press:
                    root.checkscore(3)
                    root.openquestion()

            ToggleButton:
                group:options
                id:opt4
                text:'option04'
                on_press:
                    root.openquestion()
                    root.checkscore(4)

            GridLayout:
                cols:2
                spacing:30
                Button:
                    text:'Next'
                    on_release:
                        root.openquestion()
                Button:
                    text:'Exit'
                    on_release:
                        exit()
```

I don't think there is any need for JSON file, please just assume that there are some questions and answers for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the `state` of all the `ToggleButtons` to be `normal` when a question is opened, then add code to set their states to `normal` in your `openquestion()` method. Also, note that `on_press` is triggered whenever you click on a `ToggleButton`. If you want the action to depend on whether the `state` is `down` or `normal`, then you need to put that logic in the code that gets triggered. So, in your `openquestion()` method you can add a line for each `ToggleButton` like:

```
self.ids.opt1.state = 'normal'
```

Then remove the `root.openquestion()` from each `on_press:` of the `ToggleButtons`.

The logic for opening a new question can then be added to the `checkscore()` method. Something like:

```
def checkscore(self, bu_id):
    global score
    global sca
    answer = data['category1']['answer'][sca]
    if (bu_id == answer):
        score += 1
    print('score: ', score, 'question: ', sca + 1, 'button pressed: ', bu_id, 'answer no:', answer)
    sca += 1
    Clock.schedule_once(self.openquestion, 1)
```

I added the delay, using `Clock.schedule_once()`, so that the user will notice the change. You could also add a `Popup` or something to notify the user of whether the question was answered correctly or not. Using the `Clock.schedule_once()` requires a small change to the `openquestion()` signature:

```
def openquestion(self, *args):
```

Comment: thank you I got it, how to tackle this problem. The thing i used is that i created another function for which every option is in normal state and using Clock.schedule_once(self.function_name, 0.2) with this the user can see which selection he made and the state will return to normal after 0.2 seconds.